# How to refresh 2 panels at same time?

Tags: extjs, extjs6.2, pimcore-v5

I have a page on an application which contains 2 panels. When i click on the grid refresh option, i want both panel to refresh.

Full code on this link:
http://168.63.49.171:9089/bundles/referenceapp/js/generic-grid-view.js

on the left is the grid panel and on the right the detailView panel

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by [`Ext.suspendLayouts();`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.html#method-suspendLayouts) and next [`Ext.resumeLayouts(true);`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.html#method-resumeLayouts).

> Stops layouts from happening in the whole framework.
>
> It's useful to suspend the layout activity while updating multiple components and containers:

```
Ext.suspendLayouts();
// refresh panels here
Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
```